# unable to catch errors in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How Can I handle error in React-Native

So this is my error enums

```
export const frontendErrors = {
    INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER_ENTERED: 'Sorry you have entered invalid phone number'
}
```

From my phoneAuth.js file, I am throwing error in catch statement like this

```
catch (err) {
    const errorSearch = 'auth/invalid-phone-number'
    if (err.message.includes(errorSearch)) {
     throw new Error(frontendErrors.INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER_ENTERED)
    }
```

And When I catching the error in the parent component

```
catch (error) {
           console.log(error)
            this.dropDownAlertRef.alertWithType('error', 'Error', error)
        }
```

in the log I am getting my error as an object and like this

```
Error: Sorry you have entered invalid phone number
```

The `dropdownAlertRef` takes in string so it is logging an empty object i.e.

```
this.dropDownAlertRef.alertWithType('error', 'Error', 'Invalid phone number')
```

this will log error.

**What have I tried?**

Doing, `console.log(error.Error)` gives **undefined**. How can I access my error?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(error)`? Afaik that the should be the error object you threw in the previous catch.

Comment: @Clarity I am not throwing error object. I am throwing error like this `frontendErrors.INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER_ENTER` from my first code snippet, that happens to be a string `'Sorry you have entered invalid phone number'`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this.

```
console.log(error.message)
```

For more refrence you can refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)